# Wrapping all elements in RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two recyclerViews (one under second). How to make them not to scale and resize to all elements height, so their scrolling won't be necessary and all items will be visible by scrolling main ScrollView?
Now it looks that:

[image]

My xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_detail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivPoster"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Title"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvDate"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="01.01.2001" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvRate"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="5.10/10" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btFav"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Mark as favourite"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvOverview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Lorem Ipsum" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#000df0"
                    android:text="Trailers:" />


                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/trailerRecyclerView"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#000df0"
                    android:text="Reviews:" />
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/reviewRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest *solution* to your problem is to use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` as the root scrolling element.

but...

if you really think about all this, it's not really a solution in terms of the performance of your code. Because it will look as desired but it will not be really efficient.

If your `RecyclerView` wraps its contents (the way you want it to) it inflates all items at once, and not really uses its `recycling` capabilities. It does not reuse any items it just keeps everything in memory. Essentially it becomes a component that creates a ton of `Views` using an `Adapter` based on some data, instead of a `RecyclerView`.

The way you should implement a thing like that is to create an `Adapter` that inflates multiple types of `Views` (4 types to be exact in your case), and use a single `RecyclerView` instead of your whole `ScrollView`. There are multiple threads here on SO that describe how to create such `Adapters`. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type).

To help you a bit more, here's how you should plan your view types:

[image]